# Trivial representation in tensor square

Tags: representation-theory

Taken from another question in this website. I am not sure why the following statement is true.

Suppose $G$ is a group and $V$ an irreducible representation of $G$. One has that $V⊗V≅Λ^2(V)⊕Sym^2(V)$. It is well-known that if the trivial representation appears as a subrepresentation of $Λ^2(V)$ then $V$ is of quaternionic type; while if the trivial representation appears as a subrepresentation of $Sym^2(V)$ then $V$ is a of real type.

I am trying to build a a bilinear form $B:V⊗V\to C$ that is symmetric (or alternating) that is $G$-invariant, non-degenerate, and then go from there. However, I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try googling Frobenius-Schur indicator.

Comment: Frank Adams' book _Lectures on Lie Groups_ explains these things very clearly.